# If $E$ is a nonempty closed set of real numbers bounded above, $\sup E$ is in $E$.

Tags: real-analysis

On Rudin, theorem 2.28 is like the below.

> Let $E$ be a nonempty set of real numbers which is bounded above.
>
> Let $y= \sup E$. Then  $y\in \bar E$.  Hence  $y\in E$ if $E$ is closed.

What about infimum? If $E$ is closed and bounded, and if $x = \inf E$,  $x\in E$?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Consider the definition of a closed set: one which contains all its limit points. If $\inf E$ was not in the set, and $E$ was closed, then $\inf E$ must not be a limit point of $E$. But this will form a contradiction!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\inf E = -(\sup (-E))$

Answer (score 0):

If $E$ is closed and bounded below, then $-E = \{-x : x \in E\}$ is closed and bounded above. Then $\sup -E \in -E$, and $\sup -E= - \inf E$; hence, $\inf E \in E$ as desired. So, yes.